# Bot listening to another bot in group conversation

Tags: skype, botframework, slack

I have built a few bots with Bot Framework. One of them (let's call her BOT1) is an experiment that needs to listen to all messages in a group conversation (Slack, or Skype) that is invited to.

Works great when there are users and BOT1 are invited in the channel.

However when I invite my other bot (BOT2) - BOT 1 only receives messages that are sent by the users and not messages that sent by BOT2.

Is this by design? Is there a way I can allow BOT 1 to listen to all messages? I can't find any setting in the Bot Framework that works.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent a "Bot Storm" (i.e. never ending conversation loops between bots), the channels do not allow bot to bot communication.  If scenario is one in which you manage both the bots in question, you can always send the messages through a back channel.